# dual boot from two different harddrives, windows and lubuntu not working

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, dual-boot, bootable

I have a computer with two harddrives. I first installed my Windows 8.1 on my ssd taking up the whole drive. Then on my second 2TB I made 3 partitions. 1TB is dedicated to external storage, 500GB is decidcated to lubuntu, 2GB to swap space, and the rest is just free. So after I installed Windows, I installed lubuntu on the 500GB partition. When the computer starts up I get a blank screen. I get two options for booting, from my ssd or cd drive, when I choose ssd the screen is blank, and there is no option to boot from my hhd which contains linux either. How can I fix this so I can boot from either linux or windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think Grub is missing in your system, Try using this bootable iso [Here](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/) to install GRUB on your machine. it's pretty straight forward. I had great success with this software Rescatuxin the past. Try using the Repair Boot option as well. Goodluck